# How to insert large list data into MySQL table using Python SQL.Connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

```py
data = [
    {"question": "How old was Harry?", "options": ["10", "20", "none of the above"], "answer": "10"},
    {"question": "example question", "options": ["1", "2", "3"], "answer": "1"},
]

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo VALUES ('{}','{}','{}');".format("1234", "test", data))
my_database.commit()
```

I used the above lines of code to commit the changes but the Interpreter,Throws an error like

> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'question': 'How old was Harry?', 'options': ['10', '20', 'none of the above'], '' at line 1

and at the SQL Table, I have assigned 3 Columns `(eid(VARCHAR(6)),ename(VARCHAR(10)),questions(BLOB)`.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: if you want to insert many rows then you should use `executemany()`.

Comment: if you want to insert only question then you should use `for item in data:` and use `execute()` with `item['question']`. And if you want to put all dictionary with `question` and `options` and `answer` then it may need to convert it to `JSON string` before inserting.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you created with `.format()` because you create totally wrong query

Comment: Don't use string formatting to create queries, use `cursor.execute()` parameter substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the values being inserted into a list of tuples. Then use a parametrized query along with `cursor.executemany()`.

```
import json

params = [("1234", "test", json.dumps(d)) for d in data]

mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO userinfo VALUES (%s,%s,%s);", params)
my_database.commit()
```

Comment: Thank You For Answering the Question.I tried with this Code,but unfortunately it was throwing some error. So, In order to solve this Problem. I converted all the data in the dictionary to String format(By using Join funtion) and then Inserted it into the mySQL Server table.It worked quiet Perfect. While Fetching this String i have created a Decode Function to retrieve the Dictionary format from the String format.

Comment: If you tell me what the error was, I can probably fix it. Converting the dictionary to a string makes no sense if you just want the question text.

Comment: I thought the `questions` column should just contain the question. What do you actually want?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `json.dumps()`

Comment: ok i will try again